# Rust / Bevy - Keep track of target

Tags: rust, bevy

I have a Struct `Enemy` as well as a Struct `Turret`. The goal is once a turret spots an enemy, It should keep track of it, attacking it until it is either dead or out of sight.

I have a query

```rs
fn update_turrets(mut enemy_query: Query<(&mut Enemy, Entity)>, mut turret_query: Query<(&mut Turret)>) {
...
}
```

where I can find possible targets for a Turret. As mentioned, once a target has been found, the tower should lock it. Coming from C++ I would have stored a pointer/reference of the Enemy as member in the Turret Struct, thus i tried doing that

```rs
pub struct Turret {
    pub target: *mut Enemy,
}
```

This gives me the following error: `*mut Enemy cannot be sent between threads safely` which makes sense to me. Furthermore it looks like there is no way to "ignore" that as bevy seems to demands it.

Afterwards I tried to save the entity id as `u32` as member in `Turret` instead and building a Hashmap `HashMap<u32, *mut Enemy>` at the beginning of each iteration but this seems to be very inefficient because I would  have to rebuild that hashmap on each iteration.

What is the "rust-way" of solving this efficiently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't try to keep a reference to a component. Keep a handle on the entity:

```
pub struct Turret {
    pub target: Option<Entity>,
}
```

Then, if you need to access the `Enemy` component, you can access it by passing the entity handle to [`.get()`](https://docs.rs/bevy/latest/bevy/prelude/struct.Query.html#method.get) on an enemy query.